# Does JAXB always ignore 'extra' elements not specified in @XmlType/propOrder?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If I have a class annotated with

`@XmlType(name = "someDTO", propOrder = {
    "firstField",
    "secondField",
})`

but the XML (from a SOAP response, say) looks like

`<return><firstField>a</firstField><secondField>b</secondField><thirdField>c</thirdField></return>`

My object will still get firstField and secondField populated, and thirdField is ignored.

Why is this? Will this always be the case? Is there a way to prevent object creation if extra fields are present?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations will complain if there are properties mapped to XML elements that are not included in the `propOrder`.  `propOder` on `@XmlType` is not used to control which elements are included/excluded.

**Options for Excluding Properties**

1. If you want to exclude less than half of the properties then I would suggest marking the ones you wish to exclude with `@XmlTransient`.
2. If you wish to exclude more than half of the properties then I would suggest using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` and annotating the properties you wish to include.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html

Comment: Do you know if there are any JAXB implementations that will complain if there are XML elements that aren't mapped to any properties?

Comment: @Derek - You can set a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller`, that should report a `warning` when unmapped content is hit.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, what about the need to have more then one case? for example, one time i need a specific field, and an other time not.. what can i do for that?

Comment: Additionally the XmlTransient annotation has to be added on the setter of the field just as XmlElement annotations.